# Sidenav not showing when i minimise the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am trying to do the Sidenav, when i have a full screen, the menu displays but when i minimize the browser the menu button shows but when i click it, it doesn't display anything. I don't know why. I am using **Materialize css**. http://jsfiddle.net/xdrL9e83/8/. When i run it in Jsfiddle it shows the Toggle icon being outside Navbar. I don't know why

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Booking</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#">Patients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
    <li class="bold"><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Patients</a></li>
    <li class="bold"><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
</nav>
```

The Javascript

```
<script>
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind making a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Seems to show for me when clicking the toggle icon

Comment: Yeah i want to move the toggle icon inside the Navbar opposite Booking. it looks like its outside.

Comment: Oh ok, can you edit your question to state that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DIV is closed in the wrong place. It needs to close after the content of your Nav.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Booking</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#">Patients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li class="bold"><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Patients</a></li>
    <li class="bold"><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/xdrL9e83/14/

Comment: I corrected that but still when i click the toggle button its still the same i doesn't display the list but when i maximise the browser, the menu is shown. I don't know whats going on. It works well in JsFiddle

Comment: Updated, now working. You had "fixed" in the side-nav that was keeping it visible when the page expaned.

Comment: Yeah it works very well in Jsfiddle but not working in browsers like google chrome, safari. maybe i am missing some thing.

Comment: My JSFiddle works well in Google Chrome. Do you have a link?

Comment: Over here http://localhost:8000/index.html#. Try minimize it and click the toggle button.

Comment: Sorry, I can't view your localhost. You need a hosted example, maybe try deploying to heroku?

Comment: I am trying to deploy to heroku but the push is rejected. its the phone gap app.

Answer (score 0):

Put the menu toggle icon (`mdi-navigation-menu`) at the top..

```
<nav>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>    
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Booking</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons"></i></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#">Patients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
    <li class="bold"><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Patients</a></li>
    <li class="bold"><a href="#">Patients History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Add Patient</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/mMvlUnsNRT